# Hear water running in basement pipe near sump pump

Tags: basement

I recently bought a house and have found clear standing water in back yard and can hear water running in basement but nothing is turned on in the house .  I am on a well and have septic.  The  basement had been flooded somehow by previous owner and they had cut the line to sump pump but that has been replaced and line fixed.   There is a black corrugated pipe that feeds into bottom of sump pump don't know what it is for .  Obviously no water meter since not city water.   Any ideas ?

Comment: The black corrugated pipe is "drain tile" and is what supplies your sump pail. Has the sump been running? How has your water bill been?